# injecting dependencies in to an angular app wrapped in a closure

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, module, global-variables, closures

I am having trouble injecting dependancies inside a closure, which wraps around angular. How do I include dependencies inside angular when it is wrapped inside a closure. Angular is being bootstrapped in index.html. 
An example accomplishing this in a plunker would help. Here is my code.
Let me know if there are any ambiguities.

```
(function(angular){
angular.module('myApp', ['restangular', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute',
'decipher.tags', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.typeahead',
'angularMoment', 'textAngular', 'ui.event', 'ui.mask', 'ui.validate',
'toaster', 'ngImgCrop']).
config(function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider,RestangularProvider,
versionedUrl, decipherTagsOptions, mobileAppUrl,
mobileAppDownloadLink,mobileAllowedViews)  })();})(angular);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass them the way you are passing angular:

```
(function(angular, dep1, dep2, dep3){
angular.module('myApp', ['restangular', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute',
'decipher.tags', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.typeahead',
'angularMoment', 'textAngular', 'ui.event', 'ui.mask', 'ui.validate',
'toaster', 'ngImgCrop']).
config(function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider,RestangularProvider,
versionedUrl, decipherTagsOptions, mobileAppUrl,
mobileAppDownloadLink,mobileAllowedViews)  })();})(angular, dep1, dep2, dep3);
```

Comment: So I just tried that with ngRoute and it says: Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.      (function(angular,ngRoute){

  angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);


})(angular);

Comment: You need to include the script for ngRoute in your html file, no need to pass it as a dependency (unless you are using 2 versions of that as well) in that case, you may want to take a look at requirejs.

Comment: It is included, and there are not two versions of it.

Comment: My code (function(angular,ngRoute){

  angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);


})(angular,ngRoute);       ReferenceError: ngRoute is not defined      ;Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: @Khan how can you possibly have 2 routers in the same page?

Comment: @charlietfl my main concern is to simply accomplish the task above. So if you have knowledge of angular, closures, dependancies, and the module pattern. I would appreciate the help. As it stands the solution provided does not work, and if it does please provide a plunker  and we can move on from there.